# Wifi does not work after suspend - ubuntu 20.10 - MT7630e

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.10, modprobe

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10:

```
dsm@dsm ~> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

```
dsm@dsm ~> uname -a
Linux dsm 5.8.0-45-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 13:24:51 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My wifi works when I shut down and power on my laptop, but it stops working when I suspend and start my laptop.

This is some information about my wifi and its driver.

```
dsm@dsm ~> sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: fc:4d:d4:53:4c:14
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt76x0e driverversion=5.8.0-45-generic firmware=1.0.07-b370 ip=192.168.1.41 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:b0600000-b06fffff
```

Now after suspending and starting again, I can see my wlo1 in `ifconfig`, the `Enable Wifi` checkbox is ticked in my xfce desktop but I can't find any available wifi and it does not automatically connect to my home wifi router.

I searched and came across two solutions:

This one (https://askubuntu.com/a/1180966/828610) does not work. I still can not find any available wifi.

This one (https://askubuntu.com/a/949644/828610) does not work.

```
dsm@dsm ~> sudo /sbin/modprobe -v -r mt76x0e
rmmod mt76x0e
rmmod mt76x0_common
rmmod mt76x02_lib
rmmod mt76
rmmod mac80211
rmmod libarc4
```

```
dsm@dsm ~> sudo /sbin/modprobe -v  mt76x0e
insmod /lib/modules/5.8.0-45-generic/kernel/lib/crypto/libarc4.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.8.0-45-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.8.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt76.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.8.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt76x02-lib.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.8.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt76x0/mt76x0-common.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.8.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt76x0/mt76x0e.ko
```

```
dsm@dsm ~> sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

After the above three commands, there is no wlo1 in `ifconfig`:

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a0:1d:48:a8:b0:68  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1819  bytes 172422 (172.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1819  bytes 172422 (172.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.198  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
        inet6 fe80::c2d4:4c06:2ae8:542c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 92:b4:41:b7:5e:91  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3712  bytes 1759030 (1.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3845  bytes 685418 (685.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And the `configuration` details are gone from `sudo lshw -C network`!

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0600000-b06fffff
```

And wifi doesn't work.

When I restart my laptop, everything works again!

What should I do?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You can try going back to the 5.4 kernel that works for a lot of people.

Comment: Powersaving settings is a classic forUSB wifi.  Might want to check out what options you have

Comment: @SimonBanks that isn't a USB wifi device.  The results from terminal for `dmesg | grep mt76` might be helpful after it doesn't work